# search with comma separated values in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am quite new in elastic search here so if anybody can help me here

Suppose I have selected

```
1) Category - Hollywood
2) Sub-Category - Bond Special
3) Genre - Action & Drama & Comedy ( as multiple selection will be there )
4) Language - English, Russian and Hindi ( as multiple selection will be there)
5) Release Year - 1990,1999,2000 ( as multiple selection will be there)
6) 3D Movie - True OR False (any one will be selected)
7) SortBy - “A-Z”OR “Z-A” OR “Date”
```

Can anyone help me in making this query for elastic-search. I will use "match_phrase" for making AND condition but the issue is matching parameters or search parameter will be multiple and comma separated (u can say).
and my index array is given below : -

```
[_source] => Array (
                                [id] => 43
                                [value] => GREENBERG
                                [imageName] => Done
                                [date] => (1905) USA (Bengali)
                                [language] => (Bengali) | 1905 |  1.47hrs
                                [directorName] => Alejandro González Iñárritu, Ang Lee
                                [castForSearch] => Ben Stiller, John Turturro
                                [viewDetailsUrl] => /movie/greenberg
                                [movieType] => Animation
                                [rating] => 0
                                [cast] => Ben Stiller, John Turturro, Olivier Martinez
                                [synopsis] => A man from Los Angeles, who moved to New York years ago, returns to L.A. to figure out his life while he house-sits for his brother. He soon sparks with his brother's assistant.
                                [code] => HLR06
                                [type] => Non-3D
                                [trailer] => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cwdliqOGTLw
                                [imdb_code] => 1234654
                                [tags] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Animation
                                    )

                                [genre] => Adventure
                                [languages] => Bengali
                                [categories_filter] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Category 2,Hollywood
                                    )

                                [sub_categories_filter] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Sub-Category 1,Sub-Category 4,Sub-Category 5,Sub-Category 6,Sub-Category 7
                                    )

                                    )
```

---

```
Weekly Sunday 12 AM
everyday 12 AM 
every day 12:15 AM
daily 12:01 AM
daily 12:01 AM
```

---

```
joinScreenCancellationScheduler - Weekly Sunday 12 AM 
0 0 * * 7 curl <url>
goLiveDate - everyday 12 AM 
0 0 * * * curl <url>
nearestDateDisable - every day 12:15 AM
15 0 * * * curl <url>
reminderOfEvent - daily 12:01 AM
01 0 * * * curl <url>
thresholdNotMet - daily 12:01 AM
daily 12:01 AM
```

Answer (score 1):

- To match against one of multiple possible values, use a [`terms query`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html). You don't need a `match_phrase` query because you're not doing any sort of free-text matching.
- You'll need to split the comma-separated values into arrays before indexing your data into Elasticsearch (or use a comma-separated [tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-tokenizers.html)).
- Your use case suggests that you don't care about scoring but only about filtering, in which case your query should probably just have a filter.
- Sorting is not the same as filtering; for your A-Z/Z-A/Date sorting you'll need to use a `sort` clause outside of the query.

The final thing would probably look like this:

```
GET /my_index/my_type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        "terms": { "genre": ["Action", "Drama", "Comedy"] },
        "terms": { "language": ["English", "Russian", "Hindi"] },
        // more terms filters
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": { "title": "asc" }
}
```